# OpenCV2 setting VideoBackend

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

Referring to the opencv VideoCapture documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#videocapture-set), there are a few properties that only work DC1394 v 2.x backend (specifically CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE is what I want to change). Looking at the buildInformation for openCV on my machine I see it is compiled with support for DC1394 v 2.x, FFMPEG, Gstreamer. I cannot see to figure out how to set the video backend when initializing VideoCapture. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the VideoCapture [source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/highgui/src/cap.cpp#L113) [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/highgui/src/cap.cpp#L369) there doesn't seem to be a way to open with a specific backend in opencv 2.4.

In fact it will just pick the first backend available it can find with a defined order in the code (for example lets suppose you have opencv compiled for ffmpeg and gstreamer, the order ffmpeg first and gstreamer second, if you distribute your binary to someone and they have gstreamer but not ffmpeg it will fail to open the video capture but continue to search for the next option, in this case gstreamer). So as far as I can see you have 3 choices to use the DC1394 backend:

1. Modify the source so it always tries to search for DC1394 first (or even further add a function to choose a backend)
2. Compile with just support for DC1394 as a video backend
3. Convert your code to opencv 3.x which has the option to set a backend when [opening](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html) the video capturer.

Comment: Thanks @Aram. I cannot change the backend at runtime to DC1394 with the following command in python-opencv version 4.1.2. cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://user:pass@192.168.0.90/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=1920x1080&compression=20&color=1&mirror=0&fps=25',apiPreference=cv2.CAP_DC1394)